# cabal update not working

Tags: haskell, cabal

I just did a fresh install of GHC 7.6.3, followed by installing the latest platform. But when I run cabal update, I get:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: <file descriptor: 8>: does not exist
```

What file descriptor is this referring to, and how can I fix this problem?

I've [reported this issue on github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1750) but haven't gotten any help.

Comment: What is the `cabal` version ?

Comment: version 1.16.0.2; I've updated the question with a printout

Comment: I tend to avoid the platform as it is quite conservative (e.g., current platform-2013.2.0.0 has containers-0.4.* while ghc-7.6.3 has containers-0.5.* wired in). So, my recommendation is: just install ghc, then "cabal install cabal-install", and then other packages on demand. - Of course I know there are good reasons for having and using a stable platform.

Comment: about containers - actually the doc is misleading: http://www.haskell.org/platform/changelog.html says 0.4 but the cabal file (linked from the page) says 0.5

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 The only cabal available to me is the one through the platform.  I can't build it from source, either, because I need to use cabal to fetch the dependencies!

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to the way the file system is set up on this particular machine.  (So upgrading cabal will not make much difference.)  But since the error message doesn't say what file it's trying to access, I can't fix it.

Comment: on unix/linux, you can always use `strace` to see the actual OS calls. Cf. http://chadfowler.com/blog/2014/01/26/the-magic-of-strace/